# Get email address from employee's id stored in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to get email address based on employee id.

I copy the employee ids from Excel and paste them in the "To" field of Outlook mail.

I am unable to click `ctrl + K` using the macro code.

I use the below code to paste the employee ids in Outlook application.

```
Sub Combinedata()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Dim outRec As Object
 
    count = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To count
        s = s & Cells(i, 1) & ";"
    Next
    'Range("D2") = s
  
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  
    On Error GoTo 0    
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail                   
        .To = s                  
        .Display                                    
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please fix your spacing in the question No need for your code to cover an entire page due to having 5 empty spaces. If you have to go this route, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/address-book/obtain-the-e-mail-address-of-a-recipient) link may be of interest

Answer (score 1):

`.Recipients.ResolveAll` replicates ctrl + K.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
'
' If desperate declare as variant

Sub Combinedata()

Dim i As Long
Dim count As Long

Dim s As String

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim outMail As Object

count = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To count
    s = s & Cells(i, 1) & ";"
Next

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With outMail
    .To = s
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
    .Display
End With

End Sub
```